# Search and Replace using Regular Expressions Openoffice macro

Tags: openoffice.org

How Can I Search and Replace text using Regular Expressions in Openoffice macros?

I am trying

```
oDoc = ThisComponent

Public Function findReplace(oDoc As Object, findStr As String, replaceStr As String) As Integer 
   oSearch = oDoc.createSearchDescriptor
   oSearch.searchAll = False
   oSearch.SearchString = findStr
   oSearch.ReplaceString = replaceStr
   oDoc.replaceAll(oSearch)
End Function


findReplace(oDoc, ".
", "    ")
```

I make this question because I need to find ".\n" (dot breakline) and replace with other character. In the above code I obtain syntax error.

Also I trying

```
findReplace(oDoc, "."+chr(13), "    ")
```

But that does not works

Answer (score 0):

To use a regular expression, do this:

```vb
oSearch.SearchRegularExpression = True
```

Searching for newlines is a special case, because the newline is the end of the match, not part of the match.  For paragraph breaks, match `\.$`.  For line breaks, use `\.\n`.

Check out these links:

- [Search strings and line breaks with pyUNO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912147/search-strings-and-line-breaks-with-pyuno)
- https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=70784