# Remove carriage return in python macro for libre or open office

Tags: python, regex, macros, libreoffice, carriage-return

I try to write a macro for libre/Open office in python.

i use this for replace some string and it's work :

```
document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
search = document.createSearchDescriptor()
search.SearchString = "\:\Z"
search.SearchAll = True
search.SearchCaseSensitive = False
search.SearchRegularExpression = True
selsFound = document.findAll(search)

if selsFound.getCount() == 0:
    return
for selIndex in range(0, selsFound.getCount()):
    selFound = selsFound.getByIndex(selIndex)

    selFound.setString("")
```

But now i want to remove a carriage after and i can't find how.
for exemple :

```
Mister Dean :
blablablalblal lbbla
```

to

```
Mister Dean : blablablablabla
```

I try with \n or \r but libre-office does not recognize the term.

Thanks for all :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search strings and line breaks with pyUNO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33912147/search-strings-and-line-breaks-with-pyuno)

Comment: Thx ! I Not exactly the same, but it help me. I try to delete a break line after a regex. This solution work, but it's a hack : Search the regex, create a cursor, go right, delete. It's strange that i can't find and delete the break line directly.

Comment: It makes sense to me, considering how regular expressions work in languages such as Perl.  Perl regexes will stop at newlines by default, although Perl does have the [m modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers) to provide more functionality.

Answer (score 0):

My (LO 4.1.6.2/Linux) Online Help tells me to use a `\n` to search for a `newline character` entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If a replace instruction is not given, I get what you want.
I'm pretty sure this will work for you with Python (I actually tested it with StarBasic).

edit: corrected keyboard combination

Comment: Thx for your answer. The "\n" regex don't find anything. On python scripts and with the search tool. (LO Version: 5.1.3.2. Build ID: 1:5.1.3-0ubuntu1).
So i have to use a "hack" with :
Search regex "\:\Z", create a cursor, go right, and delete. 
But it seem not the good way.